# How to simulate the exponential growth op-amp?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, simulation, simulink

According to Wikipedia, the following is the exponential output operational amplifier.

[image]

I would like to test this out in a simulated environment and see how this functions. For example give a sine wave as the input and observe the resulting output signal.

But I do not have any prior knowledge about simulating electrical circuits. Could somebody help me out here by suggesting a way to get started with this ? Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to use simulink or why did you add that tag?

Comment: I am open to using any simulating platform for doing this. I was not sure which would be the best.

Comment: Your first step should be to **think** about how this circuit works. If the diode confuses you then make it a resistor and think how that would work. This circuit applies the input voltage directly to the diode, then the current through the diode is converted to a voltage by resistor R. Think about the relation between a voltage across a diode and the resulting current through it.

Comment: If you have no experience with a circuit simulator, there's a chance you'll use it the wrong way and you will get weird results. If you have not thought about what the result should be you could think that that weird result was the actual behavior of the circuit. That's why you should only use the simulator to **confirm** what you think the behavior should be.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The context of where I stumbled upon this is that for a simple DIY project of mine I would like the output voltage that is exponential of the input

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie And the first thing I stumbled upon is the exponential output opamp. Is there any other circuit  that would give an exponential of the input voltage as the outpu ?

Comment: Why consider other circuits? What's wrong with this one? I think you do not realize that an exponential relation will only be valid over a very small range of input voltage as a change at the input results in an **exponential** change at the output. The challenge is to keep the input voltage within that range.

Comment: Assuming you can monitor 10mV to 10  volts on the output of the opamp, or 1,000:1 range, you'll need 3 * 0.058 volts input change on the left end of the diode. If you have 10,000 ohm resistor, then 1 milliamp from the diode will produce 10 volts output. The left hand side of the diode will be about 0.6 volts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit topology you are showing is an exponential amplifier (an antilog), where the output voltage is proportional to the exponent of the input voltage.

How to simulate it? and in Simulink (as per the tags), by building a model. That is where the annoyance comes from. An antilog amplifier works because of the exponential characteristics of a PN junction and thus to simulate this you must model this characteristic.

[image]

This is where the specifics of the simulation packages becomes important. The modeling of the diode can be split into 3

1. Ideal model: This will model the diode as the textbook conduction/blocking
2. Ron model: A slight improvement but treating the diode characteristics during conduction as linear. Valid for power calcs.
3. Exponential model: Be it SPICE or MAST or SIMSCAPE.

For simulink, the base Simscape's electrical domain only offers #2.  The Electronics module does offer an exponential model and this is key as this is the behaviour such an amplifier relies on.

The current equation of a diode can be summaries as
\$ I_f = I_{o} \cdot e^{ \frac{V_{in}}{V_t}} \$

Assuming ideal opamp and thus If must be the current flowing through the feedback resistor

\$I = I_f = \frac{V_- - V_o}{R_f} = \frac{-V_o}{R_f} \$

\$V_o  = -I_o R_{fb} e^{ \frac{V_{in}}{V_t}} \$

If you really want to model such a circuit, look into SPICE-based simulators as you need the characteristics of the diode.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVnRax.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>